# How can one be the Moderator of this Site?

Tags: support, moderators

What one should have to do to become the Moderator of Hinduism site? Can some one who is more active on Beta site but not on meta become the moderator? And on Stack overflow i have seen that election for Meta has held. Same thing will happen here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For short, elections are only done for graduated site and pro temp mod get selection in public beta.

> **How Moderators are Appointed Pro Tem**
>
> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are
>   deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
>     Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.
>
> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act
>   as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections
>   after the Beta period. Besides the normal abilities of a Moderator,
>   they will:
>
> - Have access to a special chat room where we will collectively work through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing.
> - Organize the process of selecting the site’s attributes (domain names, design issues, the FAQ, etc.).
> - Rally community support and drive the mission of getting publicity for the site.

Refer [this blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) for more details.

Comment: but what if any user is not much active in meta but most active on BETA then?

Comment: @TheDictator chances are less i think. But can't say exactly.

Comment: Still criteria for moderation is not decided here.. as its not showing on the site page and just because it's currently in BETA