# How does this site chose its moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators

How does this site chose its moderators? Whether those moderators reserve the right of banning a user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few blogs from stackoverflow to understand the concept of moderator in SE network :

- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

To know answer for your first question, its better if you go thorugh already asked and answered meta post:

[How can one be the Moderator of this Site?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-one-be-the-moderator-of-this-site)

So same happen to our site too, first there was [nomination for the  Pro Tempore Moderators](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/nominate-for-pro-tempore-moderators) and then SE staff came up with the [decision](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/184/1). This decision was not fully based on nomination only but on various other reason mentioned in above blogs.

There is no election in bet sites, so making moderators is in full hands of SE staff, after graduation we will get democratic election which seems bit far for now.

For your second question about banning:

Yes, moderator do have powers to ban a user if he do what he is not supposed to do like offending, abusing or repeatedly breaking SE policies. But bans are not permanent and can be redeemed and are of variable length. If mod misuse it, you surely can contact SE staff by [contact us](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/contact) page.

Comment: Thanks Ankit Sharma.Is there a way to contact other users through private messages on this site?

Comment: @Rickross No, you can ping them on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) or even can create your [own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) but its not private either.